# GetSentry RavenJS not importing in webpack build

Tags: angular, webpack, sentry

I've followed the [systemjs approach to installing the Raven api](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/angular2/?_ga=1.81198994.485437358.1466580957) and all working fine (as illustrated in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJCUhuPgvqgzCL3ohAW2?p=preview)).

```
//main entry point
import Raven from 'raven-js';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';
import {App} from './app';
```

And the **Raven** import is populated correctly.

However we're using WebPack for the bundling so I need to install Raven with WebPack.  Which I thought would just work.  Sadly not.

I tried doing an issue reproduction with [WebpackBin](http://www.webpackbin.com/4JqkROEHW) but sadly the debugger doesn't work well with, so I've created a repository at the following:

https://github.com/toepoke/raven-webpack

```
import Raven            from 'raven-js'; 
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { provide, ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

console.assert(Raven !== undefined, "Raven object is not populated :-(");
```

In Chrome DevTools the above assertion will fail because the **Raven** import is **undefined**.

As detailed in the ReadMe the Raven javascript object just isn't populated and I cannot see why.

I would be most grateful if someone could take a look.

Many thanks,
Franz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above was raised with Get Sentry:

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/issues/622

They have made some modifications, and I've updated [my repo](https://github.com/toepoke/raven-webpack) with the answer.

Hope this helps someone else too.